# Replace 3-way switch with duplex 3-way and single pole switch

Tags: electrical, lighting

How do I replace a 3-way switch with a duplex 3 way and single pole switch. The image is my current wiring configuration. The switch on the right is where I need to add the duplex switch. What do I do with the neutral wire from the new light?[image]

Comment: Are you adding another light and this is why you need another switch?  I am unsure about your question. There is no neutral in the right side switch box.

Comment: I need to add another light.

Comment: You need another light that will be switched independently of the one in the drawing, or do you want both to be switched on/off together? If the first is what you want, it's going to take running more wire than you think.

Comment: Is replacing the existing wiring an option here?

Comment: Your drawing appears to be condulet, is it actually that or romex?

Answer (score 3):

### Old fashioned way: You can't do that.

You can't just tap power any old place.

When you have a system that has switch(es) and a light, there is only one place you can tap power from - and that's where power is coming into the system.   In this case, that is the leftmost switch.

That's that. No sale.

### New-fangled way: Use Smart Switches

You need a pair of smart switches: a smart-switch *master* and a smart-switch *remote*.  The smart-switch remote can be entirely wireless and run on a battery; it can just be stuck to the wall with double-sided tape.

So you reassign all wires as follows:

- White = actual neutral, for real
- Black = always-hot
- Red = switched-hot (where used) otherwise unused.

You stick the smart switch *master* in the left box. Black and white wires all go together and with the smart switch black-white. Smart-switch red goes to the red wire.

Up in the lamp, all blacks go together. All whites go together with a pigtail to the lamp. The red from the left switch goes to the lamp hot. The red from the white switch is capped off unused.

In the right switch box, you cap off the red wire, won't use it.  Black and white are always-hot and neutral.  You wire that just like a standard 1-way "power to the switch" type wiring with a plain 1-way switch.

As far as the smart switch remote, either blow the right box out into a 2-gang box (in which case the smart switch remote can grab always-hot and neutral to power itself), or just use a wireless smart switch remote stuck to the wall next to the switch.

Answer (score 2):

This is going to need either a new cable dedicated to the new light, or (possibly) smart switches.

- Hot

You don't have *hot* in the 2nd box. What is labeled as "hot white wire taped black" is actually "traveler white wire taped black". Hot comes into the first switch. All wires farther along are travelers, switched hot or neutral.

- Neutral

You don't have neutral in the 2nd box. It goes from the first box to the light and that's it.

You can't even get away with "just a new cable from light to switch" because that would get you neutral but not hot. You need a new cable all the way from the first box, or from any other convenient location, such as a nearby receptacle, even if it is on a different circuit. You can have multiple circuits switched inside one box, as long as you keep the hot and neutral wires paired correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the cable between the existing light and the right hand switch does not have enough cores. You will either need to replace that cable with a 4 core (plus ground) cable or run a new power source for the new switch.